# How to build program assets with Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Say I have a package `MyLib` with the following directory structure

```
MyLib/
    src/
       MyLib/
           Display.hs
           Build.hs
    data/
        01.png
        02.png
        03.png
        04.png
    img/
        SpriteSheet.png
```

The images in `data` are the "source" image files used to create `img/SpriteSheet.png`, by a function called `build` in a module in the package, `MyLib.Build`. `data` and it's contents are under version control, but `img/SpriteSheet.png` isn't. `img/SpriteSheet.png` is included in the cabal file as a `datafile`, but the images in `data` are not.

When `MyLib` is a dependency of another package, is it possible to get stack to run `MyLib.Build.build` before/after installing it? `MyLib` would be listed as an `extra-dep`, with a local absolute path and git commit specified.